# Brother MFC-9460CDN change default scan folder on mac

Tags: mac, scanner, setup, all-in-one

How can I change the default folder where my MFC-9460 saves scanned documents on my Mac when I scan from the Device itself and not via the ControlCenter? Currently, it saves every Document in an obscure folder at /private/tmp/ and I haven't found an option on the device or the ControlCenter 2 Software to change this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im using mfc240c but hope this would help: right click Brother's icon on top right of screen-->open, click 'configuration' on the pop up window, choose scan-->file, you can change that under destination folder.

i think for your mfc 9460cdn it's sth similar

Comment: Right in front of me but I didn't notice... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find a way to change the default, and if the default stays the same from session to session, you could use a [folder-watching script](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.20/20.07/FolderWatching/index.html) to automatically move files to a folder of your preference, whenever they appear in the tmp/... folder.

Comment: while this is a workaround that would work, I'd still prefer a way to change the option on the device itself, if possible